# How many solutions are in equation over GF(16)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Can some one show me how to do multiplication over gf(16) step by step

I cannot determine how many solutions are in x^15 - 1

Comment: To get a bit of experience with multiplications in this field you may want to take a look at [this Q&A pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) I prepared with referrals like this in mind. As Bernard explained, you don't need that to be able to answer the question, but for some other tasks it may be necessary.

Comment: I'm fairly sure we have handled essentially the same question before, but I don't have time to look for it now. That's why I won't upvote Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to know the multiplication table in $\mathbf F_{16}$: the multiplicative group  $\mathbf F_{16}^\times$ has order $15$, hence by Lagrange's theorem, each element in this group has order a divisor of $15$.